# satellite ground track in skyfield

Tags: artificial-satellite, skyfield, ground-track

I'm trying to get the geographic location (longitude & latitude of a satellite) converted from the position in space for example:
position = (7033.45648791, 178.93192295, 0.00290722) Km.
longitude = 165.285, latitude = 0.000 degrees
i tried to use skyfield

```
from skyfield.api import wgs84

position = (7033.45648791, 178.93192295, 0.00290722)

geo = wgs84.geographic_position_of(position)

print(geo)
```

here the position is a tuple but it raises an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'center'. so I don't know what object type to use and the [documentation](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-topos.html#skyfield.toposlib.Geoid.geographic_position_of) is not helping

Comment: [Based on this](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/positions.html) position appears to be an object with some attributes (like `centre`) and not a plain tuple. Are you following code example from somewhere? If so, please provide a link to that also. (Disclaimer: I have not used skyfield).

Comment: you are right it  should have the attribute (center) but unfortunately the code is of my one mind cause I can't find an example that does so

Comment: @AJN I love Skyfield but it has always been a bit mysterious to me because there are so many classes and methods, and if there isn't a specific example for what you want to do, it's hard to guess where to begin. I wish Skyfield had a single page graphical guide to the whole class structure. This "position" business is really vexing.

Comment: @uhoh is there any other library or any way that I could use to calculate the satellite ground track

Comment: and if you could give me your contact mail or linked-in account because a want to ask some questions if you have time  for it

Comment: There is, see [my previous comment to you](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58268/satellite-ground-track-calculation#comment193123_58268) Generally Stack Exchange is not a place to make contact with people individually. If you have questions the best way is to formulate good Stack Exchange questions and post them on the site here.

Comment: ok I already tried the way you've mentioned previously that is what I've done in the code in my Question